# How to keep a variable if it exists

Tags: variables, stata

Say that I have these two datasets: `data1` and `data2`. They are the same, except that `data1` includes the `make` variable while `data2` does not.

```
sysuse auto2, clear
*create first dataset
preserve
tempfile data1
save `data1'
restore
*create second dataset
preserve
drop make
tempfile data2
save `data2'
restore
```

My problem is simple. I just want to write code so that I keep certain variables *if they exist* and keep a more limited set if not. Note that in my application, dropping variables isn't very feasible. I need to use keep.

In my toy example, I want to keep `price` and `make` for the datasets that have it (namely `data1`) and only `price` for the datasets that do not have `make` (namely `data2`).

This does not work because `keep` fails if a given variable is not in the dataset:

```
forvalues i=1/2 {
    use `data`i'', clear
    keep price make
}
```

Any suggestions? I wonder if there is some way to use an `if`+`else` statement to test if the variable `make` exists and then to either execute `keep price make` or `keep price`. Or possibly some way to use `capture keep price make` and then based on if this fails or not, go to `keep price`. Would these work or any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach: get a list of the variables that are present and look for the intersection of those and the set of variables that are wanted.

Your tentative code does nothing to `save` the results. Here I have overwritten the dataset just read in; your application may (indeed should) wish to `save` it to a new file.

```
forvalues i=1/2 {
    use `data`i'', clear
    unab present : * 
    local wanted price make 
    local available : list present & wanted 
    keep `available' 
    save, replace 
}
```

See also e.g. `isvar` from SSC and especially `capture confirm var`.